# Operações Aritméticas em Java com dados do banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

Qual é a melhor formar para calcular valores em java? Preciso de fazer um método que retorne a soma de todas entradas e saída e subtração. Exemplo: Inserir todas entradas em Double na coluna X, e todas saída Double na coluna Y (obter o total de cada coluna), para obter o saldo do dia, que é Entrada subtraído pela Saída e achar o subtTotal, que é saldo atual mais o saldo do dia. Se tiver algum exemplo será bem vindo.

Pensei e usar um looping for, mas não sei como fazer! Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter essa informação diretamente do banco usando um comando sql chamado    `Sum`.

A sintaxe se dá dessa forma:

```
Select 
    Sum('NOME_COLUNA') as resultado  
    from 
    'NOME_TABELA';
```

Tendo essa informação, você pode trabalhar com esses valores no Java, ou até mesmo, montar um select mais elaborado, que já lhe retorna as informações necessárias.